# Issues installing and using BCM43142 broadcom wireless network

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, broadcom

The most recent "fixs" that I have found and tried to no avail. 
first things first secure boot was deactivated then the following steps were taken.

sudo apt update

sudo apt dist-upgrade

reboot

no luck, also tried.

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms

reboot

no luck again

as well as others that have seemed to fix the problem for other people but still not me. I have installed pastebin and have run

wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && \

chmod +x wireless-info && \

./wireless-info

as another forum suggested but I am unsure where to go or what to do next. Help please!

https://pastebin.com/V7k01Ahf

Comment: You didn't post the result of wireless-info script. It is unclear why you thing you are uisng a Broadcom device.

Comment: That is what I am not sure how to do. just post the txt file it created directly to the forum?

Comment: Okay I have added the link to the pastebin above sorry I am a noob to all of this.

Answer (score 0):

Disable Secure Boot in BIOS and all should work. The driver is installed.

Comment: I have disabled secure boot and it says that it is booting in insecure mode on each boot now. Sorry Forgot to mention that.

Comment: Does Wi-Fi work?

Comment: It does not. I had disabled secure boot before trying any of the steps I described above.

Comment: The script says that Secure Boot is enabled. You should disable it in BIOS, not anywhere else.

Comment: okay can you give me the code to do that again. maybe I did not use the proper code.

Comment: There is no "code" to do it. It is not a terminal command. You should do it in BIOS.

Comment: okay well then that is different I used a "command" in the terminal to force the laptop to open in the menu of the bios to turn off secure boot. if there is no command then I didn't do it right. I guess I need to figure out how to properly do that then.

Comment: Okay I have confirmed to have disabled secure boot as can be seen on the new wireless-info script seen here https://pastebin.com/8eDF8XyV. I have restarted twice since turning off secure boot to no change. Any further advice?

Comment: I marked your questiona as a dupe. Did you ever read the link?